# Change comments.php causing blank page

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am working on wordpress. I open the editor in the "Appearance" section and selected the comments.php file. I carelessly commented the code using "/*" and "*/". After I update the file, it indirected to a blank page and I no longer can open my website. It always opens a blank website. How can I fix that? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is error_reporting turned on? It sounds like that you might be generating a error/warning that isn't displayed

Comment: what is error_reporting? How can I see that?

Comment: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); <-- place it at the top of your code, otherwise go Into your php.ini file and find the lines with error reporting.. Secondly you MIGHT be able to spot the issue in your error log

Comment: the problem is that I cannot see my website as well as the wordpress site of my website either.

Comment: So you can't edit it either, do you have FTP access?

Comment: how to get FTP access, through cpanel?

Comment: I'm uncertain how to help you with this, I'd recommend waiting for some one else to pop their head in and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when add the comment to the code something going wrong.
To see what is the problem please turn on the debug on wp-config.php by adding

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

or if you have it already make true and upload it then refresh.

Comment: but now I can't even log into the wordpress because it shows a blank page.

Comment: You do not need to log into wordpress, you need to log into the ftp and access the wp-config.php file and that line on it

Comment: hummm , do you have cpanel for your website ? if not you need a ftp client like [Filezila](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client). After installing it put the host your website (example.com) then the username and the password )

Comment: Yea I do have cPanel. how to do that? can you teach me in detail?

Comment: Go to the file manager, then goto public_html. right click on wp-config.php and click edit, then add the " define('WP_DEBUG', true); " before "  /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ "

Comment: then it shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE) in /home/inbetwe1/public_html/wp-content/themes/gridspace/lib/comments.php on line 51. how can i fix that?